# Second cube in database not showing to users despite role has been update

Tags: sql-server, permissions, ssas, roles, sql-server-2022

I recently added a second cube to a SSAS database.
I adjusted the roles to give users read access.
However after deployment and processing this second cube does not show up for users in Excel, SSMS and other client tools. The other cube of the solution is not affected and still accessible.

As sysadmin however I have access to the cube.

Already tried with no remedy for the problem

- Recreated the role giving full access
- Examined the cube XML for the role to show up...shows as :

```
<CubePermission dwd:design-time-name="ccdcdde4-4058-4adb-b210-1f52980818a5">
      <ID>CubePermission</ID>
      <Name>CubePermission</Name>
      <CreatedTimestamp>0001-01-01T00:00:00Z</CreatedTimestamp>
      <LastSchemaUpdate>0001-01-01T00:00:00Z</LastSchemaUpdate>
      <RoleID>Role</RoleID>
      <Read>Allowed</Read>
      <ReadSourceData>Allowed</ReadSourceData>
    </CubePermission>
```

- Deployed the database and performed a "Process Full" for the database containing the 2 cubes
- Removed all calculations from the MDX script only leaving the CALCULATE command

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason: The second cube had the property visible set to false. Therefore it did not show to users regardless of the access they had. Setting the property visible to true solved the issue.